# Union of all gender female in two tables

Tags: mysql, union

I want to union all females from the dependent table and all females from employee table this is my query but it doesn't execute :((( + i have to use union operator :

```
SELECT Em_FName AS 'Employes Name ', Dep_FName as 'Dependant Name '
FROM evnt_db.employee as e,evnt_db.dependent as d
where  Dep_gender='F'
Union 
SELECT Em_FName AS 'Employes Name ', Dep_FName as 'Dependant Name '
FROM evnt_db.employee as e,evnt_db.dependent as d
where Em_gender='F' ;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "_it doesn't execute_" What do you mean by that? Doesn't it return any result? Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: it throws an error of unknown  column Em_gender in where clause

Comment: This means there is no `Em_gender` field in `evnt_db.employee`

Comment: Column `Em_gender` belongs to `employee` or `dependent` table?

Comment: It belongs to employees table

Comment: Note that this way to write joins `FROM table1, table2` is deprecated since about 25 years. Consider using proper `JOIN`

Comment: btw, reading the two queries you can do it with one using a `OR` in the where clause...

Comment: @LelioFaieta yea you are right but i have to use the union operator

Comment: Show us the structure of the table employee

Comment: @Cid I edited it in the question

Comment: I can't see image because of my proxy. Never post table structure as image, since we can't copy paste to rebuild it (use text instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from a space between `Em_` and `gender` in the table name in mysql. But consider these queries instead of your that makes little sense if you have to use a UNION

```
SELECT '' AS 'Employes Name ', Dep_FName as 'Dependant Name '
FROM evnt_db.dependent as d
WHERE  Dep_gender='F'
UNION 
SELECT Em_FName AS 'Employes Name ', '' as 'Dependant Name '
FROM evnt_db.employee as e,evnt_db.dependent as d
WHERE Em_gender='F' ;
```

This query will give you a column with all the dependant names, a column with all the employees names. Each column will be blank if there is a value in the other colum.
If you want all of them in a column only you can do:

```
SELECT Dep_FName as 'Dependant Name ', 'Dependant' as Type
FROM evnt_db.dependent as d
WHERE  Dep_gender='F'
UNION 
SELECT Em_FName AS 'Employes Name ', 'employee' as Type
FROM evnt_db.employee as e,evnt_db.dependent as d
WHERE Em_gender='F' ;
```

This will give you all the name in one column and on the other column the type of.

Btw: i'm pretty much sure I'm helping you to cheat on your homework

Comment: still give the error of unknown column in 'Em_gender' in where cluase

Comment: check the name of the column in the table. As far as I see there is a space between `Em_` and `gender`. That's why mysql doesn't find the column

Comment: yeah I thought so i will double check it